# Adding a length to a regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Im trying to add a length requirement to the below code.

Code: `^[a-zA-z0-9\!\$\%\&]+(?: [a-zA-z0-9\!\$\%\&]+)*$`

I want a sentence with spaces to only have around 1 to 10 characters. I want to count spaces as well. The code provided doesn't allow leading or trailing space but space between.

Comment: Should it also match a single space or consecutive spaces? Can you add which tool or language you are using?

Comment: most regex use `{m,n}` to specify a min and max length for a pattern. For example, `[0-9]{3,5}` matches 3 to 5 digits.

Comment: Can the sentence have multiple spaces? Can the spaces be consecutive?

Comment: the sentence can have multiple spaces. I know about using  {1,10} for length but i cant seem to wrap my expression the right way to have it work. its javascript by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A sentence limited to 10 chars is obscenely small but you can use:

```
^(?=^.{1,10}$)[a-zA-z0-9\!\$\%\&]+(?: [a-zA-z0-9\!\$\%\&]+)*$
```

`(?=^.{1,10}$)` = ensure that between 1 and 10 chars exist between the start and end of the string.

https://regex101.com/r/zsa1N9/1

---

I see your new comment about Javascript. You would be better off adding a check for `.length` in addition to your regex.

Comment: a length of ten was just an example for testing purposes. the actual length is 1300

Comment: @bryan3045 Okay, well then just replace the `{1,10}` with `{1,1300}`. Also, note my comment about making use of `.length`

Comment: this works by the way. Thanks